# chrome extension ajax other chrome extension

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I don't think this has been asked yet but a chrome extension ajax other chrome extension. I tried but failed. It's being ajaxed though jquery. My main goal is to get the current chrome theme background.

I get this error:

Denying load of chrome-extension:///manifest.json. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Code I tried:

```
$.get( "chrome-extension://<ID>/manifest.json", function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "popup.html"
    },
    "description": "<description>",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "<name>",
    "permissions": [ "tabs","management","*://*/*" ,"<all_urls>"],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["*"],
   "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot read the data of another extension unless the resource is listed in the [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) section of the **other extension's** manifest file.

For your specific use case, you'd better use the [`chrome.management`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) API to get information about the other extension:

```js
chrome.management.get('extension ID here', function(result) {
    // See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo
});
```

Comment: I was trying get to current theme's background. I guest I will have find a different way. I hate the chrome API.